# Projective bundles on projective spaces and birational contractions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm a beginner of algebraic geometry and I find some questions as follows.

Consider the projective bundle (in sense of Grothendieck) $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathscr{O}(a_1)\oplus\cdots\cdots\mathscr{O}(a_r))$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$. I have the following questions:

[Q1] We know that $\mathrm{Bl}_{\mathbb{P}^a}\mathbb{P}^b=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^{b-a-1}}(\mathscr{O}(1)\oplus\mathscr{O}^{\oplus b+1})$, it there some similar description of the general $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathscr{O}(a_1)\oplus\cdots\cdots\mathscr{O}(a_r))$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Note that $\mathrm{Bl}_{\mathbb{P}^a}\mathbb{P}^b$ can be seems as blowing up the vertex of the cone of $\mathbb{P}^{b-a-1}$ in $\mathbb{P}^b$. How about general case? I guess this maybe the resolotion of singularity of some $(a_1,...,a_i,...)$-uple embedding in the bigger projective space.

[Q2] Now the Picard number of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathscr{O}(a_1)\oplus\cdots\cdots\mathscr{O}(a_r))$ is $2$, so we may have two Mori contractions. We know that maybe one of them is just $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathscr{O}(a_1)\oplus\cdots\cdots\mathscr{O}(a_r))\to \mathbb{P}^n$. What is the second one?
If there exists $a_i\neq a_j$, this one may be a divisorial contraction? Why or why not?

[Q3] Are there some results about these for general projective bundles on $\mathbb{P}^n$ or more general varieties?

Thank you for you any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. This projective bundle can be thought of a higher-dimensional scroll. Indeed, if you twist the vector bundle approperately (this does not affect the projective bundle) you can assume that all $a_i$ are positive, then you can consider the Veronese embeddings of the degrees $a_i$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, and then form a scroll with fibers $\mathbb{P}^{r-1}$.

Q2. Consider the twist of you vector bundle such that all $a_i$ are nonnegative but some are equal to zero (such a twist is unique). Then a construction similar to the above gives a morphism from your projective bundle to the cone over the subscroll that corresponds to the positive weights. This is the second extremal contraction.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!